# Why did using xargs fail in this case?

Tags: command-line, pipe, xargs

I tried to understand the usage of `xargs` and did the following experiment.

```
ls | xargs | touch
```

I want to refresh the files dates and directoris in the curent directory.

Though it is a bit *silly*,for I could use a simpler form to achieve the same effect.

In my mind, `xargs` reads from the `STDIN` and turn it into the arguments for the other command(`/bin/echo` by default if the command is not specified). Am I misunderstanding something?

It failed and I am wondering why.

Comment: It is recommended [not to parse](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) `ls` output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It needs to be like this:

```
ls | xargs touch
```

The `xargs` command runs the `touch` command with a number of strings read from stdin.  In your case, stdin for `xargs` is the output end of the pipe from `ls`.

The way you had the command:

```
ls | xargs | touch
```

`xargs` had no command to run against the strings (filenames) it would read from stdin.  In that case, `xargs` simply prints each file name, and `touch` gets the list of file names on its standard input.  But `touch` doesn't read from its standard input, and since you didn't give it any arguments, it should have printed an error message like:

```
touch: missing file operand
Try `touch --help' for more information.
```

(which you should have mentioned in your question).

Comment: Ah, so that's how it works. +1